# Diverter valve in Glacier Bay two handle kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink, diverter

My kitchen sprayer works fine, but I now only get a trickle from the spout.  Still only a trickle after removing the spout.  I'm assuming the diverter valve either needs to be cleaned or replaced, but I'm not sure how to remove it, and I'm worried about breaking it if I try the wrong thing.  Assistance identifying this faucet would also be appreciated.  Thank you.
[image: before]
After removing the spout:
[image: after]
[image: after2]

Comment: Home Depot Sells that brand.  You could take this picture down to the replacement valve section and try to identify something similar.  The center part need not have a valve with moving parts.  The output of the two handle valves just joins together, comes up the center, out the hole in front, and around the visible groove to whatever position the spout is in.  If you unmount it you can examine it more easily for plugged tubes without attempting to remove something that may not be intended to come off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just above the upper threads is a black cap.  Insert a flat screwdriver slightly between the upper treads and the cap and pry it up.  Then use a coin to unscrew the diverter.  Replacement part number is A66G391, which comes with a removal/installation tool.
[image: diverter]

Comment: Why a coin rather than a screwdriver?  To OP, if you pry it out with screwdrivers, using two on opposite sides usually does less damage than prying with one because it eliminates twist.

Comment: The diverter is hollow.  Most screwdrivers are not wide enough to engage both slots at once.

Comment: Actually, that is the wrong part.  I have that faucet.  I ordered that diverter, and it does not fit.  The diverter in the faucet is shorter and has only one O-ring.  I'm still trying to find the right part.